# Swift Combine: How can I convert `AnyPublisher<[Foo], *>` to `AnyPublisher<Foo, *>`?

Tags: swift, rx-swift, combine

How can I convert a publisher of array a certain element, to just a publisher of said element (but with more events)?

e.g. how can I convert

`AnyPublisher<[Int], Never>` to `AnyPublisher<Int, Never>`?

I think maybe what RxSwift offers with its [`from` operator](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/c6c0c540109678b96639c25e9c0ebe4a6d7a69a9/RxSwift/Observables/Sequence.swift#L34-L36) is similar to what I want to do.

I guess I want the inverse of Combine [`collect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204692-collect)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
func example(publisher: AnyPublisher<[Foo], Never>) -> AnyPublisher<Foo, Never> {
    return publisher
        .map { $0.publisher }
        .switchToLatest()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: How does `.flatMap { $0.publisher }` compare to `.map { $0.publisher }.switchToLatest()` ? Maybe the latter is what one wants in the most cases? Or are they _completely_ equivalent?

Comment: They are not equivalent. If the downstream subscriber throttles the publisher then there could be problems. Nice catch.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want to do is to use a `FlatMap` on the publisher of the `Foo` array, using a function which converts the `Foo` array to an `Observable` of `Foo` (which is where the `from` comes in).

```
.flatMap { $0.publisher }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it would be nicer if example code was provided.

Comment: I derived it based on knowing Rx API and a cursory overview of the project on Github (source code)... Not a Swift programmer myself ;)